# How can I write a loop that cycles through my if statements?

Tags: java, loops

I am currently making a farming game where you use pots to farm plants in. Every pot I own should be clickable and should present the option to plant a seed in it. So far, I have came up with a non-optimal way to implement this. I was wondering if I can use a loop to neatly cycle through each statement in fewer lines of code.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
if (HUD.pots == 1) {
    // First pot 230, 502, 40, 50. Every new pot adds 50 to X
    if (mouseOver(mx, my, 230, 502, 40, 50)) {
        AudioPlayer.getSound("menu_sound").play();
        Game.gameState = STATE.Game;
        return;
    }
} else if(HUD.pots == 2) {
    if (mouseOver(mx, my, 230, 502, 40, 50)) {
        AudioPlayer.getSound("menu_sound").play();
        Game.gameState = STATE.Game;
        return;
    } else if (mouseOver(mx, my, 280, 502, 40, 50)) {
        AudioPlayer.getSound("menu_sound").play();
        Game.gameState = STATE.Game;
        return;
    }
} else if (HUD.pots == 3) {
    if (mouseOver(mx, my, 230, 502, 40, 50)) {
        AudioPlayer.getSound("menu_sound").play();
        Game.gameState = STATE.Game;
        return;
    } else if (mouseOver(mx, my, 280, 502, 40, 50)) {
        AudioPlayer.getSound("menu_sound").play();
        Game.gameState = STATE.Game;
        return;
    } else if (mouseOver(mx, my, 330, 502, 40, 50)) {
         AudioPlayer.getSound("menu_sound").play();
         Game.gameState = STATE.Game;
         return;
    }
}
```

And when I eventually add more pots to the game, which I intend to do, I will need many lines to iterate over all of them.

I have a similar question for another situation: How can I make it to spawn `x + 50` every time I buy a new pot?
Code:

```
// Buy Pot 
if (mouseOver(mx, my, 220, 140, 40, 20)) {
    AudioPlayer.getSound("menu_sound").play();
    if (HUD.money >= UpgradePrices.potPrice) {
        HUD.money -= UpgradePrices.potPrice;
        HUD.pots += 1;
    if (HUD.pots == 1) {
        handler.addObject(new Pot((int)230, (int)502, ID.Pot, handler));
    } else if (HUD.pots == 2) {
        handler.addObject(new Pot((int)280, (int)502, ID.Pot, handler));
    } else if (HUD.pots == 3) {
         handler.addObject(new Pot((int)330, (int)502, ID.Pot, handler));
    }

    Game.gameState = STATE.Upgrades;
    return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For buying pots, you may apply the same idea:

```
if (mouseOver(mx, my, 220, 140, 40, 20)){       //Assume this position is fixed
    AudioPlayer.getSound("menu_sound").play();
    if (HUD.money >= UpgradePrices.potPrice){
        HUD.money -= UpgradePrices.potPrice;
        HUD.pots += 1;
    }
    for(int x=0; x<HUD.pots; x++){             //Once again, this will replace all the ifs
        handler.addObject(new Pot(( 230+(x*50), 502, ID.Pot, handler )))
    }
}
```

Comment: @s8an-AB Take a look at the solution here for buying pots. I posted another solution here for the 2nd part for clarity.

Comment: It did not work :) Until I removed one set of () that was written in there. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 4):

See if this is what you want:

```
for(int x=0; x<HUD.pots; x++){
    if(mouseOver(mx, my, 230+(x*50), 502, 40, 50)){
        AudioPlayer.getSound("menu_sound").play();
        Game.gameState = STATE.Game;
        return;
    }           
}
```

This will replace the long series of all your if-statements.
However, it seems to me you are hard coding quite a bit of things here..

Comment: @s8an-AB Try and let me know the outcome.

Comment: Yes I've had the feeling that I were hard coding. All of my codes feel so stiff and strict :) And yes it works perfectly :) Thank you!

Comment: I cannot get that loop to work for the second set of code. I tried to alter the code, but that did not work.

Comment: @s8an-AB You mean for buying pots?

Comment: For the buying pots indeed.